# Session reusing in aiohhttp

Tags: python, async-await, aiohttp, sanic

I try to reuse HTTP-session as aiohttp docs advice

> Don’t create a session per request. Most likely you need a session per
>   application which performs all requests altogether.

But usual pattern which I use with requests lib doesn`t work:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

async def get_u(self, id):
    async with self.session.get('url') as resp:
        json_resp = await resp.json()

        return json_resp.get('data', {})
```

Then I try to

```
await client.get_u(1)
```

I got error

```
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Any workarounds with async_timeout didn't help.

Another way is working:

```
async def get_u(self, id):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        with async_timeout.timeout(3):
            async with session.get('url') as resp:
                json_resp = await resp.json()
                return json_resp.get('data', {})
```

But it seems like creating session per request.

So my question: how to properly reuse aiohttp-session?

UPD: minimal working example. Sanic application with following view

```
import aiohttp
from sanic.views import HTTPMethodView


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self.url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'

    async def get(self):
        async with self.session.get(self.url) as resp:
            json_resp = await resp.json()

            return json_resp


client = Client()


class ExView(HTTPMethodView):
    async def get(self, request):
        todo = await client.get()
        print(todo)
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal executable example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an aiohttp ClientSession with Sanic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638347/how-to-use-an-aiohttp-clientsession-with-sanic)

Comment: I also have a same question. I've been able to avoid `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task` by passing `timeout=None` to `session`, but I get other kind of various. The doc suggests creating a persistent session, but doesn't tell how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same error.  The solution for me was initializing the client within an async function.  EG:

```
class SearchClient(object):

    def __init__(self, search_url: str, api_key: str):
        self.search_url = search_url
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.session = None

    async def _get(self, url, attempt=1):
        if self.session is None:
            self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True)

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'api-key': self.api_key
        }
        logger.info("Running Search: {}".format(url))
        try:
            with timeout(60):
                async with self.session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
                    results = await response.json()
                    return results
```

Comment: The only addendum I would make is if not using the context manager with ClientSession we need to [manually close the session](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request) on existing the app with  `await session.close()`. See [How to close aiohttp ClientSession](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317307/175584)

Answer (score 1):

For example you can create `ClientSession` on app start (using `on_startup` signal https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#signals). 
Store it to you app (aiohttp application has dict interface for such issues https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#id4) and get access to your session through `request.app['YOU_CLIENT_SESSION']` in request.

Comment: This is very useful to know but it seems convoluted to pass to the client class. Perhaps an example here would be helpful?